# Error message failed to launch + IOS/cordova

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I am using cordova(phonegap) 2.1.0 for IOS app development. 
When i execute my code through xcode, i get the following error message:

```
failed to launch '/Users/blah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp1-gpcoqhtpqjazwsbkyzcvoxwukjmy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testapp1.app/testapp1
```

I am not able to figure out why this error is coming because i have not made any code changes and before it was not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

1 - remove the app from the iPhone Simulator

2 - remove the contents of the DerivedData folder

3 - Clean & Build the project, restart Xcode, and reboot your device.